# How to stop a face from being affected by transformations?

Tags: rigging, constraints

I have a Muscle that I'm using [`Bendy Bones`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/properties/bendy_bones.html) to transform. and was wondering if there was a way for me to make a face not be effected by it. So it doesn't do this

[image: Arm Relaxed]

[image: Arm Bent]

In pic 1 the ligaments are fine but in pic 2 the ligaments are dragged away thanks to the transformation of the bendy bones.)

I have a hook on the edge of the ligaments but it still drags them
What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: select the vertices that you want to stay still and remove them from the vertex group, or decrease the weight for this vertex group?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to remove the Vertices from the Vertex Group. Thanks moonboots